# How to auto save highcharts as image in specific folder

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, highcharts

I am creating chart using highcharts and rails, i want to save chart under app/assets/image/ folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways you can convert your map to image which are listed  below. To save image in your application you need to use carrierwave or file handling option.

You can do it with direct html2canvas conversion:

http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/examples.html

Highchart also provide way to export image :

http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.buttons.contextButton.onclick

Rails gem that uses wkhtmltoimage for image conversion:

https://github.com/csquared/IMGKit

Comment: the example in the jsfiddle is asking for the path to save write?we want to take the path automatically